# Classes get shared in IB between different Xcode projects in an Xcode 4 workspace. Why?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4

I have two projects in a Xcode 4 workspace.

Then, I drag a new Object into my XIB file in one of the project to instantiate a new object. Why on earth can I choose as the object's class a class in the other project? This is messed up, and causes weird dependencies between different projects.

I even had one case where I had two different classes in each project, but the classes had the same name. But the XIB file in one of the projects referenced the class in the other project -- not in the project in which the XIB file was!

Is this a known Xcode 4 bug, or have I got something wrong? If it's a bug, what are some potential temporary remedies to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM. Workspaces are made so it's easy to share objects between projects in the same workspace.

Remedy:
File > New > New Workspace...

Place projects in different workspaces if you want to separate them more strictly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So basically, files between projects should not have the same names, or you will possibly get incorrect references in IB? Also, I forgot to mention that I tried deleting one of the project from the workspace, but I still kept getting references to action methods and outlets in IB from that deleted project's class (i.e. from the class from the deleted project, not from the class from the current project where the XIB file is).